# Selector of pointer for method from base type in go

Tags: go, language-lawyer, specifications

It's obvious that the following code will work fine:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    a int
}

func (t T) M() {
    fmt.Println("M method")
}

func main() {
    var t = &T{1}
    t.M() // it's interesting
}
```

But as I can see from [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

> For a value x of type T or *T where T is not a pointer or interface type, **x.f denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in T** where there is such an f. If there is not exactly one f with shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.

But in example `M` is not from `*T`, it's from `T`. I know that `*T` includes method set of `T` but as I can see specification doesn't tell us about method set of `*T`. Do I understand the specification wrong or correctness of the line with comment is based on some other specification rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You quoted:

> `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest **depth** in `T`

The quote refers to **depth**. ["Definition" of *depth* is:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

> A selector `f` may denote a field or method `f` of a type `T`, or it may refer to a field or method `f` of a nested [embedded field](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) of `T`. **The number of embedded fields traversed to reach `f` is called its depth in `T`.** The depth of a field or method `f` declared in `T` is zero. The depth of a field or method `f` declared in an embedded field `A` in `T` is the depth of `f` in `A` plus one.

The key is **embedding**. Your struct does not embed a single type. So by definition, the depth of your `T.M` is **zero**.

Your `t` variable is of type `*T` (that is the type of the `&T{}` expression, which is [taking the address](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) of a struct [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals): it generates a pointer to a unique variable initialized with the literal's value).

And quoting from [Spec: Method values:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)

> As with [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors), a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: `pt.Mv` is equivalent to `(*pt).Mv`.

`t.M` is a reference to the non-interface method `T.M`, and since `t` is a pointer, it will be automatically dereferenced: `(*t).M()`.

Now let's see an example where the "at the shallowest depth" does matter.

```
type T struct{}

func (t T) M() { fmt.Println("T.M()") }

type T2 struct {
    T // Embed T
}

func (t T2) M() { fmt.Println("T2.M()") }

func main() {
    var t T = T{}
    var t2 T2 = T2{T: t}
    t2.M()
}
```

In `main()` we call `t2.M()`. Since `T2` embeds `T`, this could refer to `T2.T.M` and `T2.M`. But since depth of `T2.T.M` is **one** and depth of `T2.M` is **zero**, `T2.M` being at the shallowest depth in `T2`, therefore `t2.M` will denote `T2.M` and not `T2.T.M`, so the above example prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VQoI_Rcrln0)):

```
T2.M()
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Method Sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T).